# SwiftUI View Transition matching to an Segmented Picker

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-animation

Is it possible to have three (more than 2!) views that are animated in and out from the sides according to an `Picker` with the `SegmentedPickerStyle()` style?

Having only 2 items in the picker makes the job static and thus a `.transition(.move(edge: .leading))` on the first and a `.transition(.move(edge: .trailing))` on the last view is sufficient. But what about more than 2?

Maybe there is a way to make the `edge: ...` parameter of the transition dynamically set to `.leading` or `.trailing` and depending on whether how the new value of the binding is greater or less than the current on.

I created the following sketch to demonstrate the issue of having the same view (view 2) with a different transition depending on whether a view on its right or left is selected. Please see this only as an example, the problem is not restricted to only three segments, nor only the middle view, nor only disappearing transitions etc..

[image]

Comment: Can you share a picture of the required result?

Comment: I'm sure this is possible. Please provide some code.

Comment: I was thinking about this issue before starting to code so unfortunately I do not have any, a picture might also not describe the desired animation well, just imagine the segmented control picker, each segemnt responsible for showing it's dedicated view below. The view animation (slide in/out from left/right) shoul dmatch the movement of the white background bar in the Picker (the standard segmented control picker, we all know from apple), that indicates the current selection.

Comment: I adde a sketch describing the desired behaviour for one particular example case that should explain the desired result and the overall problem quite well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update** The secret sauce is to make sure the transition fires with an animation and tell it what direction to go before doing so. Give this a try:

```
class TabControllerContext : ObservableObject {
    @Published var selected = panels.one { didSet {
        if previous != selected {
            insertion = selected.makeMove(previous)
            removal = previous.makeMove(selected)

            withAnimation {
                trigger = selected
                previous = selected
            }
        }
    }}
    
    @Published var trigger = panels.one
    @Published var previous = panels.one
    var insertion : AnyTransition = .move(edge: .leading)
    var removal : AnyTransition = .move(edge: .trailing)
}

struct TabsWithTransitionsView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var context : TabControllerContext
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Picker("Select Panel", selection: $context.selected) {
                ForEach(panels.allCases) { panel in
                    panel.label.tag(panel)
                }
            }.pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
            
            ForEach(panels.allCases) { panel in
                if context.trigger == panel {
                    panel.label
                        .background(panel.color)
                        .transition(.asymmetric(insertion: context.insertion, removal: context.removal))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

enum panels : Int, CaseIterable, Identifiable {
    case one = 1
    case two = 2
    case three = 3
    
    var label : some View {
        switch self {
        case .one:
            return Label("Tab One", systemImage: "1.circle")
        case .two:
            return Label("Tab Two", systemImage: "2.square")
        case .three:
            return Label("Tab Three", systemImage: "asterisk.circle")
        }
    }
    
    var color : Color {
        switch self {
        case .one: return Color.red.opacity(0.5)
        case .two: return Color.green.opacity(0.5)
        case .three: return Color.blue.opacity(0.5)
        }
    }
    
    func makeMove(_ otherPanel: panels) -> AnyTransition {
        return otherPanel.rawValue < self.rawValue ? .move(edge: .trailing) : .move(edge: .leading)
    }
    
    // so the enum can be indentified when enumerated
    var id : Int { self.rawValue }
}

struct TabsWithTransitionsView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TabsWithTransitionsView().environmentObject(TabControllerContext())
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see how that should work, because each view other than the rightmost or leftmost on has to slide in from both left and right depending on on whether the new selection is on its right or left.

Comment: @lenny added logic to make those transitions dynamic. Please try the updated code.

Comment: that totally did the trick! thank youfor the detailed example, I was actually able to break it down into only a custom binding and two state variables for the in/out transition.

Comment: You are very welcome! The pic was very helpful.